# How to use Sequelize ORM with multiple Schemas

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js, multi-tenant

So I have a multi-tenant application. So each tenant has their own schema and there is a common schema between all of them. The common database is created and maintained programmatically by sequelize using the folders and files created by `sequelize init`. This allows me to use ORM functions such as `findAll` or `findByPK` for the common schema but to do any CRUD on one of the tenants schemas I use a mysql connection with raw queries. My question is: Is it possible interface with the tenants schemas using ORM? Like can I change the current default schema being used by sequelize so that I can use `findAll` for a tenants schema?

Please let me know if this question is confusing and I will try ask it in a different way.

Comment: You can always indicate `schema` option in each individual model definition if it's what you are trying to achieve

Comment: This doesn't work. Sequealize complains if you don't set a database on the connection, and if you use a model with a schema defined, then the table is formed like this:
<Connection Database>. <Model Schema>. <Model Name>